# Mask-rcnn:Need advice for the Prediction about the root/handler and orientation of balloons

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

By reading the mask rcnn balloon example(https://engineering.matterport.com/splash-of-color-instance-segmentation-with-mask-r-cnn-and-tensorflow-7c761e238b46),now :

**My objective:**

Feed my balloon dataset with orientation and root position annotation info to the modified mask_rcnn and then it can finally learn how to detect the orientation(in degree) and root position for every balloon in val dataset.

**Status**:

For traning datasets, I used the VIA to draw a line(from root/handler to the very bottom of each balloon) that can indicate the orientation for every balloon instance in an image, because in VIA a line contains 2 points, thus the 1st point in json file will be the root coordinate of each balloon instance.
the picture below shows the my idea:
[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsmEr.png)

I developed some programs which can :

1. get the root coordinate (float value)for all the balloon instance in an image from the json file
2. calculate the orientation (angle in degree, float value with 2 digits)by the 2 points of the line for all balloons
   Issues:

I think to send the acquired angle and root position info to the mask rcnn, in balloon.py, I need to add them to the
```

```
class BalloonDataset(utils.Dataset):

   def load_balloon(self, dataset_dir, subset):
    .......
     self.add_image(
           "balloon",
           image_id=a['filename'],  # use file name as a unique image id
           path=image_path,
           width=width, height=height,
           polygons=polygons,
           angles=angles,
           roots=roots
            )
```

``` 
is that correct?

I think i also need to define the loss function for root and orientation in model.py, but the type i gusee i should use the apsame one as the mask loss or box loss,could someone give me some hints?

couls someone give me some idea where should i change in the model.py or others?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understood your problem statement correctly (what do you mean with root/handler?) but Mask-RCNN is not designed for this. There have been some discussion of how to modify that repo for keypoint / bounding box problems but it's complicated and not advisable. There is better methods for this, an example being Faster-RCNN.

Matterports Mask-RCNN is however excellent and perhaps you could use it without heavily modifying the model only adding some opencv and the simple geometry of balloons.

1. Generate masks as shown in the tutorial. No modifications needed.
2. Use cv2.minAreaRect() on the masks to get the bounding boxes and rotations.
3. The end points of the balloons could be approximated to be at the center of the shorter sides of the bounding boxes.

Hope this can help you in your project!

### In response to edit:

Your image really helped to understand your problem statement. I think if you want to use Mask-RCNN for this you could do the following

1. Create masks for the roots of the balloons. (Again; Mask-RCNN is good for creating masks, not for keypoint detection or anything else. Look up other methods for keypoints to avoid having to create masks and reduce training / inference time)
2. If all images are just balloons and white background like this you could use opencvs cv2.moments to get the center of mass for both the root mask and the balloon contour and draw a line between them in order to (approximately) get the rotation.

Comment: Hi,thank you very much for your reply!, I will re-ask my question in order to clearly state my idea, thank you!